# VBA: Excel range always coming up as Empty?

Tags: function, vba, excel, excel-2007

I have 2 fields in an Excel Workbook:

**1. MED     - Range("J13:K13")**

**Formula:   =IF(D5=1,"X","")**

**2. NON-MED - Range("L13:M13")**

**Formula:   =IF(D5=2,"X","")**

When using the below code, the fields are always coming up as NOT empty, thus saving a value of '1':

```
    '1. Med
    If Not IsEmpty(range("J13:K13").value) Then
        Worksheets("FeedSamples").range("AK" & newRow).value = 1
    Else
        Worksheets("FeedSamples").range("AK" & newRow).value = 0
    End If
    '2. Non-Med
    If Not IsEmpty(range("L13:M13").value) Then
        Worksheets("FeedSamples").range("AL" & newRow).value = 1
    Else
        Worksheets("FeedSamples").range("AL" & newRow).value = 0
    End If
```

I tried using the following in my IF statement, but the count is always '1':

```
    '1. Med
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(range("J13:K13")) = 0 Then
```

Anyone have any ideas? If the field has an 'X' for a value (or length count of 1) then I need to save '1' in my other worksheet. If the field is empty (or length count of 0) then I need to save '0' in my other worksheet.

I am at a lost for why my check for IsEmpty() is not functioning correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can use `IsEmpty` on a range of cells. I can replicate this behavior, whenever I pass a range of 2+ cells, the `IsEmpty` function returns `False`.

Try using `If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("J13:K13")) = 0`

This will check for the presence of *any* values in the range, and return a value of `0` only when all cells contain no values (the range is empty), otherwise it will return a non-zero value, indicating the range is not empty.

**Revision**

The presence of formula in the range, even formula that return a null string (`""`) value will be counted by the `COUNTA` function.

You may be able to use the `COUNTIF` function:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIF(Range("J13:K13"),"") = Range("J13:K13").Cells.Count
```

This will avoid counting formulas that return a null string.

This statement evaluates `True` if and only if all cells are blank/null string values.

Comment: you keep beating me to these answers

Comment: @chancea I should get back to work now :) I'll let you have a few!

Comment: That's the weird thing. I've checked both `J13` and `K13` values individually (coming up as empty), but when I run `CountA(Range("J13:K13"))` the value always is coming up as '1'. :/

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic that means somewhere in that range there is a value

Comment: The "value" could be a space or other non-visible character like a carriage return, tab, etc.

Comment: @chancea, I think you're onto something... I checked the CountA of both J13 and K13 individually when the range is supposed to be Empty and J13 is always coming up with a '1'. My formula for the range is set by another cells value, the formula being `=IF(D5=1,"X","")`. Could `""` be getting counted as the '1' in the CountA() somehow?

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic yes I just tested that and yes `CountA` treats `""` as a value

Comment: A formula will cause that.

Comment: @DavidZemens Could you give me an example of syntax for that function?

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic revision, above :)

Comment: This may not be the entire solution... When I try `MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.Countif(range("J13"),"")` I am still receiving a value of '1' for the count when Range("J13:K13") is empty, or as set by the formula, `""`.

Comment: Wait, sorry. I didn't see the bit of code after the `=` and assumed it was the same as mine before. I THINK this may work. Let me change some statements and run a few tests.

Comment: The last bit of code is important. What we're checking to see is if the number of cells containing the blank/nullstring value is equal to the number of cells in the range. This approximates the `IsEmpty`.

Comment: Thanks for all the help and the explanation @DavidZemens! It seems that everything is functioning correctly now! :D